# NodeJS convert MYSQL Date

Tags: mysql, node.js, date-format

I'm struggling a bit with the timeformat that nodejs provides as output.

I do a MYSQL query and get a datetime back (f.e `2020-01-08 20:20:25` is a entry in my DB)
When I get the result from my query the output looks like `Wed Jan 08 2020 20:20:25 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)`

I couldn't find a method to "convert" it back to the format from my database, do you have any solution for this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a third party module named [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).  You can use `npm install moment --save` to install the module. It helps with date conversion with custom formats.

Below is my code:

```
const moment = require('moment'); // Importing the Moment.js module

const date = moment(
    "Wed Jan 08 2020 20:20:25 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)",
    "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss"
); // This is your query from MySQL

let mydate = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); // Using moment.format() with the given format, it converts the date

console.log(mydate) // Finally outputting the date to the console
```

The following code outputs: 2020-01-08 20:20:25

Comment: As of September 2020 - Moment is no longer recommended in new projects, see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 4):

when you create the instance just add the config for use dates as strings

```js
mysql.createConnection({
  dateStrings: true
});
```